# Do "range" data types in PostgreSQL correspond to First Normal Form?

Tags: postgresql, normalization

I have a task for my university project to confirm that the database I made is in Third Normal Form. I decided to use the "daterange" data type for one of the columns in my database, which basically makes it hold two dates.

My question is: will my database pass the First Normal Form check (tables not containing any composite or multi-valued attributes) if I use "datarange" as a type of one of my columns? What would be the explanation for why it is not composite or multi-valued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question, though the answer is likely to be a matter of opinion.

On the one hand, as quoted from E.F.Codd in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form),

> A relation is in first normal form if and only if no attribute domain has relations as elements.

From this point of view, since a date range can be represented as a relation (with the range start and end date as attributes), having an attribute of the date range type violates the first normal form rule.

On the other hand, that same Wikipedia page quotes Codd again like so:

> ...values in the domains on which each relation is defined are required to be atomic with respect to the DBMS.

This basically means that, as long as you don't routinely make your DBMS decompose the `daterange` values and/or manipulate their constituent parts, like you would by querying `...WHERE LOWER(my_daterange_column) <= <some date>`, and only ever retrieve and update the range values as a whole, you can claim that your `daterange` domain values are atomic and not "relations", thus meeting the 1NF criterion.

Another example of such an ambiguous data type can be found in the PostGIS' `geometry`.

The [Atomicity section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) in the quoted Wikipedia article has further discussion on this topic, which only adds uncertainty.

All in all, I think you have accidentally found yourself a project that may not have the "right" or "wrong" answer; I hope your teacher recognises that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I am going to separate the needed date values to avoid arguing with my teacher. Luckily, I found just a way to avoid using daterange. I got the purpose of creating it (having non-overlapping dates) to work for separate date values by creating an EXCLUDE constraint.

Comment: I would provide 2 answers/designs to the teacher with the daterange and as separated columns.

Comment: The question's design does not use a relation-valued attribute type, so the question does NOT violate the "no attribute domain has relations as elements" 1NF. PS The 2nd quote is from the introductory part of Codd's 1970 paper using "atomic" (and several other terms) in an everyday sense & "required to be atomic with respect to the DBMS" is everyday language used to then introduce (poorly) that elements should not be relation-valued.